# finding a time range using case statement

Tags: vb.net

good evening everyone...

could anyone help me on this?

With a "time value", eg. 08:00:00...

i want to find the range that this value falls in using case statement...

i am not good in using the time format...

anyone can help?

This is just an example: (the code is not working...is just an example)

```
datime = Now().ToString("hh:mm:ss")
Select Case datime
Case "08:00:00" To "09:00:00"
lblRange.Text = i.ToString()
Case "09:00:01" To "09:14:59"
lblRange.Text = (i - 0.25).ToString()
Case "09:15:00" To "09:29:59"
lblRange.Text = (i - 0.5).ToString()
```

Comment: Be careful with these ranges as times like 9:00:00.5 and 9:14:59.5 will cause a problem for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i wouldn't use the `Select...Case` statement, it should be used with simple conditions only. You can use an `If-Else` instead.

But since you're actually checking if a given time is between a range you could also use following code which uses LINQ.

First you need to define a collection which holds all ranges. You can use a `List(Of YourClass)` or even an array of an anoymous type:

```
Dim ranges = {
    New With {.Start = TimeSpan.FromHours(8), .End = TimeSpan.FromHours(9)},
    New With {.Start = New TimeSpan(9, 0, 1), .End = New TimeSpan(9, 14, 59)},
    New With {.Start = New TimeSpan(9, 15, 0), .End = New TimeSpan(9, 29, 59)}
}
```

You want to compare `TimeSpan`s, you get the current time by `Date.Now.TimeOfDay`.

```
Dim now As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay
Dim matchingRange = ranges.
    FirstOrDefault(Function(r) now >= r.Start AndAlso now <= r.End)
```

`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` returns the first where the time is in range or `Nothing` otherwise.

```
If matchingRange IsNot Nothing Then
    lblRange.Text = String.Format("Between {0} and {1}",
                                  matchingRange.Start,
                                  matchingRange.End)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't follow Tim's advice you can use this

```
    Dim timeToCheck As DateTime = #7:10:00 PM#

    Select Case timeToCheck.TimeOfDay
        Case New TimeSpan(8, 0, 0) To New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)
            Stop
        Case New TimeSpan(9, 0, 1) To New TimeSpan(9, 14, 59)
            Stop
        Case New TimeSpan(9, 15, 0) To New TimeSpan(9, 29, 59)
            Stop
        Case New TimeSpan(19, 0, 0) To New TimeSpan(19, 14, 59)
            Stop
        Case Else
            Stop
    End Select
```

You do NOT want to use strings.